# Can we parallel shift a vector from one plane to another plane

Tags: vectors

When 2 vectors are in a plane ,we can parallel shift them so that they have same intial point such that they have same direction and magnitude as intial , but when 2 vectors are in different planes say one in X-Z plane and other in Y-Z plane  how can we parallel shift them to add ? Or simply can we shift the vectors from one plane to another?

If yes,

We know that each vector has a unique direction given by r=xi^+ yj^+zk^ where x y z are it's components in X Yand Z direction respectively. Then if we shift (parallel shift) then it's components may change, this will give us another vector ? Though this new vector has same direction as r but it's components may be different (like the new vector may r'=-xi+yj-zk). I am not getting this . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An operator that transports vectors from one plane to another is sometimes called a “discrete connection” and has been studied in the context of simplicial complexes etc.

One canonical way to transport a vector from one plane to another: rotate the first plane about the edge common to both planes until the first plane is parallel to the second. Then slide the vector onto the second plane.

Comment: My question was if transport a vector without changing it's direction and magnitude ,the representation changes like if it was r=ai^+bj^ may change to -ai^+bj^( if we shift it to 2nd quadrant from first quadrant) how is it possible then?